# Spring Data Predicate - Search Attribute in Child Collection

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Hi I'm writing a Specification.toPredicate() method to search entities based on search criteria entered in a standard form.  I have it working for searches on the parent entity but need to search an attribute of the children (which are mapped and held in a Set).  The mapping is many to many.

The search on the child attribute will return all parent items where search matches on an entered child attribute.

For example, using a simple relation between Teacher [Parent] and Pupil [Child]

```
        @Entity
        class Teacher {
           @Id
           @Column(name = "ID")
           private Long id; 

           @Column(name = "NAME")
           private String name;

           @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
           @JoinTable(name = "TEACHER_PUPIL",
                                 joinColumns =
           @JoinColumn(name = "TEACHER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
                                 inverseJoinColumns =
           @JoinColumn(name = "PUPIL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
           Set<Pupil> pupils;

                     // etc.

     }

        @Entity
        class Pupil {
           @Id
           @Column(name = "ID")
           private Long id;

           @Column(name = "NAME")
           private String name;
           // etc.

    }

            public class ClassSpecifications {


                public static Specification<Teacher> filterCriteria(final MyCustomForm myForm) {

                              return new Specification<Teacher>() {

                                @Override
                                public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Teacher> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

                                    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
                                                // *** this works fine.  
                                if (myForm.getSearchName() != null) {                   
                                                            Expression<String> expression = root.get("name");
                                        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(expression), "%" + myForm.getSearchName().toUpperCase() + "%"));  
                                }


                                               if (myForm.getPupilNameSearch() ! = null) {
                                                // HERE SEARCH List for the pupil's name like.
                                                }

                                criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
                                return null;

                          }


                    }





   @Repository
   public interface TeacherDAO extends JpaRepository<Teacher, Long> , JpaSpecificationExecutor<Teacher>{

    }
```

// the call will be:

```
teacherDAO.findAll(ClassSpecifications.filterCriteria(searchForm));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SetJoin<Teacher, Pupil> transactions = root.joinSet("pupils");              
Expression<String> expression = transactions.get("name");
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(expression), "%" + myForm.getPupilNameSearch().toUpperCase()+ "%"));
```